# Cannot load module 'fireBaseDatabase' as 'FirebaseDatabase'

Tags: swift, firebase, module, firebase-realtime-database

So i am new to Firebase and I was following this guys tutorial on how to connect your Swift app to Firebase and this completely works out for him fine. But when I try to import 'FirebaseDatabase' it gives me this error;

cannot load module 'fireBaseDatabase' as 'FirebaseDatabase

I was wondering how i can solve this problem. Thank you.

Here is my podfile;

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FIRBaseQuickStart' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FIRBaseQuickStart

    pod ‘Firebase’
    pod ‘Firebase/Database’

end
```

Now it says "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" when i try to run the app.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

It gives me error on the class declaration line. This is sooo frustrating.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code that relates to this? Are you saying you try to write `import FirebaseDatabase` at the top of a class? I'd like to help, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean here.

Comment: Have you founded the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was because of the project name. I had it as 'fireBaseDatabase' and turns out that complicates things. I just created another project with another name and now it's fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest (4.0) version of `Firebase` you need to use only `import Firebase` as I've understood from docs.

And for database refs:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()
```

You can find it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start)

Try it. Hope it helps.

Comment: This did not help. XCode also does not auo complete the "Database" or "FIRDatabase" yet it recognizes "Firebaseapp.configure()" and auto completes it. Also when I try to import something such as the "Firebase" method, the auto complete has them crossed out with a red line.

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan It's stupid question, but. Have you build your projects (almost with errors)? It's starting build from PODs. Only after it you can use them.

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan and can u please provide your podfile?

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan I have updated my pods yesterday. This code works fine. import FirebaseDatabase

struct Post {
   static var refToMainDataBaseNode = Database.database().reference(withPath: "MainDataBase")

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan so try to change import line